# Post model BeginCollection with same names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, collections

My model is a person contains a collection of another persons(Parents).
Every person have a collection of contacts.

**Edit.cshtml**

```
@model Person
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "", FormMethod.Post, ...))
{
    @foreach (var parent in Model.Parents)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("ParentItem", parent);
    }
    @foreach (var contact in Model.Contacts)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("ContactItem", contact);
    }
    \\other 
}
```

**ContactItem.cshtml**

```
@model Contact
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Contacts"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    \\other 
}
```

**ParentItem.cshtml**

```
@model Person
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Parents"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @foreach (var contact in Model.Contacts)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("ContactItem", contact);
    }
    \\other 
}
```

The problem appears when I add a new parent to a person (Person.Parents.first now exists), then add a Contact to a parent(Person.Parents.first.Contacts.first expected), model comes to "Save" inside an outer collection (Person.Contacts.last my new contact here) 
I think it is connected with naming of collections on the form(BeginCollectionItem("Contacts")), but how to solve it?

Comment: `BeginCollectionItem` will not work with nested collections.

Comment: [this article](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/06/06/editing-and-binding-nested-lists-with-asp-net-mvc-2/) might be useful, otherwise you can do this all client side with javascript - refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wqE6Rb) for an example

Comment: @StephenMuecke ty, article example works perfectly for me. Your client side solution is also good

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **PartialViews** you should use [EditorTemplates](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html#editor-templates) like this:

**Edit.cshtml**

```
@model Person
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "", FormMethod.Post, ...))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Parents)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Contacts)
    \\other 
}
```

In `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder create 2 views:

**Contact.cshtml**

```
@model Contact

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
\\other
```

**Person.cshtml**

```
@model Person

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Contacts)
\\other
```

Then you won't have any problems with naming becouse EditorTemplates feature will do this for you.

Comment: OP wants to dynamically add new items in the view (hence `BeginCollectionItem`) which will not work with an `EditorTemplate`

Comment: @StephenMuecke oops, you right. Then i just need to add templates approach to this answer like you use in your comment link. Also i always wondering if i need not only add, but also dynamic delete function how should i use your approach? I mean there is a trouble with index, if you delete record in the middle

Comment: Not using `BeginColletionItem()` - its adds an collection indexer based on a `Guid` and a hidden input for the indexer which allow non-zero based, non-consecutive collections to be bound. And for a client side only solution, see the fiddle I linked to (and for a simple example - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308))